# 403.14 when accessing site remotely, works on the server

Tags: team-foundation-server, iis-8.5, passthrough

A test TFS instance has just started to play up. Whilst on the server I can access http://localhost/tfs if I attempt it from a remote machine using http://tfs.it.domain.local I get a 403 error. Looking at the IIS logs it's a 403.14.

Here is the IIS log entry when I access it on the server:

```
2015-08-28 11:35:25 ::1 GET /tfs/ - 80 DOMAIN\username ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost/tfs 200 0 0 78
```

And here is the entry when I try remotely:

```
2015-08-28 11:28:42 10.103.170.11 GET / - 80 - 10.15.5.17 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/44.0.2403.157+Safari/537.36 - 403 14 0 62
```

A search online suggest that Directory Browsing must be enabled but that I think is a red herring as I can access the site on the server. I suspect it's an issue with pass-through authentication. Windows Authentication is enabled on the site by default.

Any tips?

Comment: You are accessing two different URLs in your logs, what's the log entry for remote `/tfs/` ? IIS is usually very good when providing the correct sub-status code, so 403.14 for `Directory listing denied` should be taken seriously.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that to me. IIS was correct, I should have been appending the /tfs to the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing two different URLs in your logs, what's the log entry for remote `/tfs/`?

IIS is usually very good when providing the correct sub-status code, so 403.14 for `Directory listing denied` should be taken seriously.